# Why does my Log.e() log a value without the tag?

Tags: android, kotlin

I made the GroupsActivity be the main activity of the app (launches first), but for some reason the app is only logging the message and not the tag.

[image]

The startup flow is as follows:

1. App is installed.
2. The first screen is GroupsActivity, but since this is a fresh install the user is not logged in.
3. GroupsActivity opens the SplashActivity and finishes the GroupsActivity.
4. SplashActivity opens for about 1 second (it's just a simple splash screen with the logo on it, nothing fancy), then it opens LoginSignupActivity and finishes itself.
5. On the LoginSignupActivity, I select the option to login. The LoginActivity opens, but I do not finish the LoginSignupActivity in case the user hits the back button.
6. On the LoginActivity, I provide the email/password and hit the login button.
7. On successful credentials validation, GroupsActivity is opened and I finish the LoginActivity.

At this point, I checked the log in Android Studio and found strange behavior. There is supposed to be a line in the debugger for "GroupsActivity: 3", but instead all I see is "3". The app didn't crash and there are no fatal exceptions. I'm just curious to know why it didn't log the tag in case it causes problems for me down the road.

Side note - if there is a better way to do a startup flow, let me know! I'm new to Android app dev!

Comment: What happens if you view the logs with `adb logcat`? I wonder if this is just Android Studio trying to remove "noise" (since you have two messages with the same level and tag in a row).

Comment: @BenP. logcat shows the full `E/GroupsActivity: 3`. Does this mean that logcat shows more info? I don't understand the diff between the Run tab the the logcat tab anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you use the same **tag** inside the logcat. Try to use different **tag** for example `Log.e("GroupsActivity", "1");` and `Log.e("GroupsActivity1", "3");`